# JavaFX with OpenCV start/pause webcam. FXMLLoader

Tags: opencv, javafx, fxml, fxmlloader

I am trying to learn JavaFX with the library OpenCV for my degree. I want to make a program that detects people. We can name it people counter. I saw some videos already and I want to do that too.

The problem is that I have to start to learn JavaFX and the library OpenCV.
So I started to create a simple project that starts / pause the webcam and take a snapshot. I saw someone on youtube doing this and I started to recreate it.

The problem is that I have this error:

> `Exception in Application start method`
> `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`

My code is:

**Main**

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = (BorderPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Camera.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**CameraController**

```
package application;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfByte;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture;

public class CameraController {
    // definitions
    @FXML
    private Button btn_start, btn_pause, btn_snapshot;
    @FXML
    private ImageView imgView;

    private DaemonThread myThread = null;
        int count = 0;
        VideoCapture webSource = null;

        Mat frame = new Mat();
        MatOfByte mem = new MatOfByte(); /// start button 

        @FXML
        protected void startClick(ActionEvent event) {
            webSource =new VideoCapture(0);
            myThread = new DaemonThread();
            Thread t = new Thread(myThread);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            myThread.runnable = true;
            t.start();
            btn_start.setDisable(true);
            btn_pause.setDisable(false); // stop button
        }

        @FXML
        protected void pauseClick(ActionEvent event) {}

        @FXML
        protected void snapshotClick(ActionEvent event) {}
   
        class DaemonThread implements Runnable {
            protected volatile boolean runnable = false;

            @Override
            public  void run() {
                synchronized (this) {
                    while (runnable) {
                        if (webSource.grab()) {
                            try {
                                webSource.retrieve(frame);
                                Imgcodecs.imencode(".bmp", frame, mem);
                                Image im = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(mem.toArray()));

                                BufferedImage buff = (BufferedImage) im;
                                imgView.setImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(buff, null));
                
                                if (!runnable) {
                                    System.out.println("Going to wait()");
                                    this.wait();
                                }
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                System.out.println("Error");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }
}
```

The problem is on this line:

```
BorderPane root = (BorderPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Camera.fxml"));
Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
```

Full console error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat()J
    at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.core.Mat.<init>(Mat.java:24)
    at application.CameraController.<init>(CameraController.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:927)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:15)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application application.Main
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by just adding `System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME)`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    launch(args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it worked for me  nu.pattern.OpenCV.loadShared();